# Using bsearch with an array inside a struct

Tags: c

I have the following struct definition

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int address;
    line_type_t type; /* an enum */
} label_t;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    int max;
    label_t** head;
} label_registry_t;
```

I'm trying to search it like so:

```
int label_cmp(const void* v1, const void* v2) {
    label_t* l1 = (label_t*) v1;    
    label_t* l2 = (label_t*) v2;

    return strcmp(l1->name, l2->name);
}

label_t* registry_find(label_registry_t* registry, char* name) {
    label_t** result;
    label_t label;
    label.name = name;

    result = bsearch(&label, registry->head, registry->count, sizeof(label_t*), &label_cmp);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return *result;
}
```

It is not successful. When I debug in `label_cmp`, I see the first argument is the name I expect, but the second is jibbrish. Looking at addresses, I see that `v2` is `0x804e008`, while `registry->head` is shown as `0x804e018` (actually, the debugger shows `registry->head` as `0x804e008`, but then under it `*head` as `0x804e018`).

So I imagine this has to do with word alignment, but I can't find a way to pass the right address to bsearch. I tried `registry->head + 0` and `&registry->head[0]`.

So what is the right way to use bsearch here?

Comment: `label_t*` is the size of a pointer. Is that correct?

Comment: Note: in `&label_cmp` you do not need to provide the `&`. The compiler knows to take the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find an `X`, you pass to `bsearch` an array of `X` [1] and an address of an `X`, and your comparison function accepts two addresses of `X`. To recap:

If you want to find an *int*, you pass to `bsearch` an array of *int* and an address of an *int*, and your comparison function accepts two addresses of *int*.

If you want to find a *struct*, you pass to `bsearch` an array of *struct* and an address of a *struct*, and your comparison function accepts two addresses of *struct*.

If you want to find a *pointer to struct*, you pass to `bsearch` an array of *pointers to struct* and an address of a *pointer to struct*, and your comparison function accepts two addresses of *pointer to struct*.

Now what your code has is an array of pointers to struct, and address of a struct, and a comparison function that accepts two addresses of struct. This ain't gonna work. You need to harmonise the inputs.

--
[1] An address of its first element actually, but it is not important here.